# Saving multiple records appropriately cakePHP way

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an event form which contains information related to event like: `start_time`, `finish_time` etc.

Every event bolongs to a user. The requirements are that the same type of event can be saved for multiple users, so from the form I receive a list of users as well.
Now that makes it impossible to use model's native save function and for that reason I have the following code:

```
function saveNotRepeatedEvents($event, $users){

    foreach($users as $user){

          $event['Event']['user_id'] = $user;
          $this->create();
          $this->save($event);
    }   

         return true;
    }
```

First of all, it does not allow for transactions, and I have a feeling that it can be done better, like "cakePHP way", but just cannot find anything during the research.

So the main issue would be how to intruduce transactions in this case. But any help or guidance on how to make it more cakePHP way would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you couldn't find anything then you haven't put very much effort in your research: **[Cookbook > Models > Saving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array)**

Comment: Ofcourse I have been through it, but it does not solve the problem. I do not want to save users together with events.
I only want to save events, but the problem is that every event must have a user_id, but from the form I get an array of user ids instead of just one.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question, however, in that case, just go a section upwards to [**`Model::saveMany`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array). Also it sounds as if you maybe should use a many-to-many association instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Model::saveAll($yourData)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array), which at the end will make use of a transaction (as long as your database engine supports transactions).

The main idea is that you will prepare $yourData as an array with this form

```
$yourData = array(
    array('Event' => array('user_id' => 1)),
    array('Event' => array('user_id' => 2)),
);
```

Of course, you will do this in your for loop, I am just giving you the main idea.